# Where can I find a specific vertion of the Microsoft Visual studio redistributables package?

Tags: visual-studio, redistributable

I need to package the VS redistributables as private assemblies (in a subdirectory of my application) by I do not have the right version of them (9.0.21022.8) in my Visual studio installation or my Windows/WinSxS folder.

On the MSDN website they only offer the latest update of the package, but the DLL I use depends on an older version.

Is there a place on the Microsoft website or somewhere else where I could download any version of the visual C++ redistributables package?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555? Links to other versions of VS are at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am looking for different update versions (security updates) of the redistributables for the same visual studio version.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download) actually keeps all the redistributables. However, finding specific version is not trivial. I recently had to look for this version of 2008 VC redistributables and here they are:

- [vcredist_x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) 9.0.21022.8
- [vcredist_x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) 9.0.21022.8

Please, don't forget that they contain a critical vulnerability and should be avoided whenever it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018, if you join the dev-essentials program you can get older versions. I've spent some hours looking for them too.

https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/

Answer (score 0):

In [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) you'll find links to the versions 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019.